# Call two different functions from same onclick in HTML

Tags: java, jsp, onclick

Can we make JSP Functions and Java Methods work on same OnClick of button?
For e.g.
`<button onclick="SignupValidation(); SignUpServlet.java;"/>`
Here SignupValidation() refers to JS function..

Can this be written?
And if not, then can you please guide me?

Comment: Why not try and see if it works? https://jsfiddle.net/Lqd9cqp5/. This sounds like a JavaScript question.

Comment: yes @bejado, it works...but my question is for 2 different method types.

Comment: Why not create a third method `startSignupProcess()` which calls these two?

Comment: not working @Bene

Answer (score 0):

Is SignUpServlet.java Server-side?
If this is right, you must use ajax call, because javascript can not call java method of server-side scripts directly.

You can try this.

```
//html & javascript
<button onclick="SignupValidationJSAndJSP();"/>
<script>
function SignupValidationJSAndJSP(){
      SignupValidation();
      $.ajax({
      method:'post',
      url:'/*SignUpServlet.java*/'// this is the SignUpServlet's server url.
      complete:function(res){
          if (trim("res") == 'ok')
              alert('ok');
          }
      });
}
</script>

//Server-Side    SignUpServlet.java

....
public function SignUpServletAction(){
//server side processing...
return "ok";
}
```